# rpi-imager not working in ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS x86

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

I want to use rpi-imager in ubuntu

```
sudo -i
apt update
apt install rpi-imager
rpi-imager
```

but it couldn't work.The log is:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
QGLXContext: Failed to create dummy context
qrc:/main.qml:281:21: QML Rectangle: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
Failed to create OpenGL context for format QSurfaceFormat(version 2.0, options QFlags<QSurfaceFormat::FormatOption>(), depthBufferSize 24, redBufferSize -1, greenBufferSize -1, blueBufferSize -1, alphaBufferSize -1, stencilBufferSize 8, samples -1, swapBehavior QSurfaceFormat::DoubleBuffer, swapInterval 1, colorSpace QSurfaceFormat::DefaultColorSpace, profile  QSurfaceFormat::NoProfile)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of Ubuntu are you using?
Someone posted a similar question on the official pi forum https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=286924
Turns out they just needed an update and a reboot

Comment: Thanks a lot.It just need reboot.